# Why can't we make tcpdump to not stop/exit when an interface on which it is capturing is brought down?

Tags: tcpdump, libpcap, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, tshark

If *tcpdump* is started with -i <specific_interace_name> exits if that is brought down.
However, if it is started with "*-i any*" option, it doesn't stop if *wlanX/ethX* interfaces are removed because the other interfaces (like *lo*, *dummy*, *rmnet*) are present.

And on my Android device if I want to capture packets on the *wlan0* interfaces for a longer period(which includes multiple WiFi restarts in between), with the current implementation, I wouldn't be able to do it because the *tcpdump* stops when the WiFi is turned OFF.

So how about we modify the sources of *tcpdump* and/or *libpcap* and implement something similar to "-i any". Many linux machines(at least *arm64* based android devices) have *dummy0* interface, so with a special option, we provide a functionality where we can capture packets on *wlan0* interaface and *dummy0* interface (although *dummy0* interface doesn't produce any packets), so that when *wlan0* interface is brought down as part of the WiFi OFF operation we will still have *dummy0* interface and *tcpdump* doesn't exit.

If anyone had thought on similar lines, please comments your thoughts and suggestions.

I'm planning to modify the tcpdump and/or libpcap source code from the AOSP codebase to achieve this.

Comment: Did you check if using a bond interface could solve your issue? The idea would be to create a bond device with your WiFi interface as the only child. I suspect the bond device will stay up even if the child interface goes down.

Comment: pchaigno - Thanks for a nice idea but unfortunately I won't be able to or allowed to do modifications outside tcpdump / libpcap.